# getting error when post select value

Tags: php, html

I have a small problem.

`<select name="level_id">` is not posting. 
So i get an error like : `Undefined index : level_id`

Exactly what can i do?

```
$sql1 = 'SELECT T_ABILITY.PK AS AB_PK,T_ABILITY.ABILITY_NAME AS AN,T_ABILITY_LEVEL.PK AS LE_PK,T_ABILITY_LEVEL.LEVEL_NAME AS LN
FROM T_USER_ABILITY_REL,T_ABILITY,T_ABILITY_LEVEL WHERE
T_USER_ABILITY_REL.ABILITY_FK = T_ABILITY.PK AND
T_USER_ABILITY_REL.ABILITY_LEVEL_FK = T_ABILITY_LEVEL.PK AND
T_USER_ABILITY_REL.USER_FK = '.$user_id.'
ORDER BY AN';
$stmt1 = oci_parse($conn, $sql1);
$r1    = oci_execute($stmt1);
while ($row1 = oci_fetch_array($stmt1, OCI_RETURN_NULLS + OCI_ASSOC)) {
  echo '<form method="post">';
  echo '<tr>';
  echo '<td>'.$row1["AN"].'</td>';
  echo '<input type="hidden" name="ability_id" value="'.$row1["AB_PK"].'"/>';
  echo '<td class="select-level">';
  $sql2  = 'SELECT PK,LEVEL_NAME FROM T_ABILITY_LEVEL ORDER BY LEVEL_ORDER';
  $stmt2 = oci_parse($conn, $sql2);
  $r2    = oci_execute($stmt2);
  echo '<select name="level_id" class="form-control selectpicker" data-container="body" data-live-search="true" data-size="5" title="Seviye Seçiniz">';
  while ($row2 = oci_fetch_array($stmt2, OCI_RETURN_NULLS + OCI_ASSOC)) {
    echo '<option '.($row2["PK"] == $row1["LE_PK"] ? 'selected="selected"' : "").' value="'.$row2["PK"].'">'.$row2["LEVEL_NAME"].'</option>';
  }
  echo '</select>';

  echo '<button type="submit" name="update-user-ability" class="btn btn-success">Güncelle</button>';
  echo '<button type="submit" name="delete-user-ability" class="btn btn-danger">Sil</button>';
  echo '</td>';
  echo '</tr>';
  echo '</form>';
}
```

submit part below

```
if (isset($_POST["update-user-ability"])) {

    $user_id    = $_GET["user_id"];
    $ability_id = $_POST["ability_id"];
    $level_id   = $_POST['level_id'];
```

Comment: This part of the code is without problems related to your error message. Show us the code where you reference `level_id` array index.

Comment: i added submit part

Comment: Your HTML isn't valid. You have the `ability_id` input in the table, but not inside `<td>`.

Comment: thanks but there is no problem about ability_id. I am getting error related level_id

Comment: Can you not make the form in pure `html` to avoid complications?

Comment: use isset() to prevent errors, if var don't set: `if (isset($_POST["update-user-ability"], $_GET["user_id"], $_POST["ability_id"], $_POST['level_id'])) {`

Comment: The value of `level_id` probably isn't send along, because it is a `<select>`. Not sure, but could be that only `input` values are properly posted. You could use a `<input type="hidden" name="level_id_hidden" />` and update its value with JavaScript every time the `<select>` value changes, and then use that value for the post-value: `$level_id=$_POST['level_id_hidden'];`.

Comment: how much select fields do you have after while loop?

Comment: did you try to use double-quotes in `$_POST['level_id'];` as well as in the other statements of submit part?

Comment: do you can post the output html from your php code?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Could be that the value of `level_id` isn't send along, because it is a `<select>`. Not sure, but could be that only `<input />` values are properly posted.

You could use a `<input type="hidden" name="level_id_val" />` and update its value with JavaScript every time the value of `<select name="level_id">` is changed (using [.onchange](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onchange.asp)).

Then, in PHP, use that field instead of the select: `$level_id = $_POST['level_id_val'];`

Comment: Select is as good an element for a form as any other form element. Indeed, one can use js to update a hidden input's value, but that is definitely not the right way to go.

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier don't let me stop you to actually be constructive and show us what *is* the right way

Comment: using a select, in a form, works. this is the proper way. if op is getting an undefined index, it's because they are not showing the exact code, or have a typo, or whatever strange way of doing things they are having. You are presently sharing false information: that is, the notion that selects could not be used to send value in a form. I am sorry, but that is false, and I have to tell you so. I will repeat myself: of course, one can use JS to update a hidden input and use that input. But you can be assured that forms normally don't use that way.

Comment: so yeah, after a few tests, I've confirmed the problem: op's query returns no rows, hence no values are defined for the select's name.

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier That's all I ask:) I don't mind people opposing me, I just mind them not doing it in a constructive way... I'll advice the OP to accept your answer if it works

Comment: @OkanUZUN I urge you to have a look at the other answer and if it works, accept that one instead of mine. If you can solve your problem without having to add an extra input-element, that is usually preferred. You want to cloud your code as little as possible with unnecessary elements

Comment: @myfunkyside I see you actually are reasonable! Cheers!

Comment: thank you @myfunkyside. onChange() function helped by assign value to input hidden so my problem has beed solved.

Answer (score 0):

This is because your select is empty (that is, the `oci_fetch_array($stmt2, OCI_RETURN_NULLS + OCI_ASSOC` returns no rows.)

A select, when no option are present, will not return a value to the receiving php script.

Add a default option before the loop to be sure something is passed even if your sql query returns nothing.

this script will return an empty post:

```
<html>
<body>
<form method="post">
    <select name="select"></select>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
<?php
var_dump($_POST); // array(0) { }
```

while this one will have the value 12 defined:

```
<html>
<body>
<form method="post">
    <select name="select">
        <option value="12">12</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
<?php
var_dump($_POST); // array(1) { ["select"]=> string(2) "12" }
```